# Is Spring XD the right tool choice?

Tags: hadoop, real-time, analytics

We're building an M2M IoT platform and part of the ecosystem is a Big Data storage and analytics component.

The platform connects devices at one end and provides a streaming data output using ActiveMQ to interface with the Big Data application layer.

I'm right now designing this middle layer which accepts machine data, running real time processes and stores this data in to a Hadoop storage module.

From what I see, Spring XD seems to be able to orchestrate this process from ingestion, to filtering, processing, analytics and export to Hadoop.

However, I do not know anyone who has done something like this. Anyone here who has executed something similar? Need your feedback into the choice of tool for the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Spring XD is great with RabbitMQ, for ActiveMQ you can use the JMS connector.

For more information take a look at Spring Integration, which is the main underpinnings and has been around for ever.

Spring XD runs on YARN or Zookeeper which are very solid.

I have seen it used for orchestration of big data in a few places.